# Spark Streaming/Kafka classes not found

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am trying to create a Spark [`StreamingContext`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/streaming-programming-guide.html) to stream messages from a Kafka topic. So I added the following dependency to my build:

```
"org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka_2.10:1.6.2"
```

Then I created the following class:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.streaming.Seconds
import org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext
import org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream

import kafka.serializer.StringDecoder
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils

object StreamingApp {
    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        def messageConsumer(): StreamingContext = {
            val topicName : String = "my-topic"
            val brokerHostAndPort : String = "mykafka.example.com:9092"

            val ssc = new StreamingContext(SparkContext.getOrCreate(), Seconds(10))

            createKafkaStream(ssc, topicName, brokerHostAndPort).foreachRDD(rdd => {
                rdd.foreach { msg =>
                    // TODO: Implement message processing here.
                }
            })

            ssc
        }

        StreamingContext.getActive.foreach {
            _.stop(stopSparkContext = false)
        }

        val ssc = StreamingContext.getActiveOrCreate(messageConsumer)
        ssc.start()
        ssc.awaitTermination()
    }

    def createKafkaStream(ssc: StreamingContext,
            kafkaTopics: String, brokers: String): DStream[(String, 
            String)] = {
        val kafkaParams = Map[String, String](
            "bootstrap.servers" -> brokers,
            "key.deserializer" -> "StringDeserializer",
            "value.deserializer" -> "StringDeserializer",
            "auto.offset.reset" -> "latest",
            "enable.auto.commit" -> "false"
        )        

        KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String,String,StringDecoder,StringDecoder](
            ssc, kafkaParams, Set(kafkaTopics))
    }
}
```

When I compile this (via Ant, but that shouldn't matter) I get `scalac` compiler errors:

```
[scalac] /Users/myuser/workspace/myapp/src/main/groovy/com/me/myapp/utils/scala/StreamingApp.scala:11: error: not found: object kafka
[scalac] import kafka.serializer.StringDecoder
[scalac]        ^
[scalac] /Users/myuser/workspace/myapp/src/main/groovy/com/me/myapp/utils/scala/StreamingApp.scala:12: error: object kafka is not a member of package org.apache.spark.streaming
[scalac] import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils
[scalac]                                   ^
[scalac] /Users/myuser/workspace/myapp/src/main/groovy/com/me/myapp/utils/scala/StreamingApp.scala:63: error: not found: value KafkaUtils
[scalac]         KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String,String,StringDecoder,StringDecoder](ssc, kafkaParams, Set(kafkaTopics))
[scalac]         ^
[scalac] three errors found
```

Am I missing any dependencies here? Or not using the correct dependencies? Or coding something incorrectly?

---

#### Update:

Interestingly enough, when I change my dependency to:

```
"org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka_2.10:1.6.1"
```

These compiler errors go away...

Answer (score 0):

the artifact ID for the kafka dependency should be like:

```
spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11
```

Hope it works for you.